# close form A when open form B

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I use

```
open_from('b');
```

in `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger for open form `B` from form `A`.
how to close form `A` when I open form `B` by using `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` in oracle form builder?

Comment: use `new_form` instead of `open_form`

Comment: thank you @yasel problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
close_form('a');
open_form('b');
```

or

```
call_form('b');
```

By using call_form it will hide the form A and then display B and when user will exit from B then A will be active.

Answer (score 0):

use `new_form` Built-in instead of `open_form`.

`new_form` will Exits the current form and enters the indicated form.

```
    PROCEDURE NEW_FORM (
        formmodule_name VARCHAR2,
        rollback_mode NUMBER,
        query_mode NUMBER,
        data_mode NUMBER,
        paramlist_name VARCHAR2);
```

Where:

**formmodule_name**

- Then name of the called form (must be enclosed in single quotes). Datatype is VARCHAR2.

**rollback_mode**

- TO_SAVEPOINT (The default.): Oracle Forms will roll back all uncommitted changes (including posted changes) to the current form’s savepoint.
- NO_ROLLBACK: Oracle Forms will exit the current form without rolling back to a savepoint.
- FULL_ROLLBACK: Oracle Forms rolls back all uncommitted changes (including posted changes) that were made during the current Runform session.

**query_mode**

- NO_QUERY_ONLY (The default.) Runs the indicated form normally, allowing the end user to perform inserts, updates, and deletes in the form.
- QUERY_ONLY Runs the indicated form in query-only mode; end users can query records, but cannot perform inserts, updates or deletes.

**data_mode**

- NO_SHARE_LIBRARY_DATA (The default.): At runtime, Oracle Forms will not share data between forms that have identical libraries attached (at design time).
- SHARE_LIBRARY_DATA: At runtime, Oracle Forms will share data between forms that have identical libraries attached (at design time).

**paramlist_name**

- The name you gave the parameter list object when you defined it. Datatype is VARCHAR2.

**simple example:**

```
    NEW_FORM ('FORM_NAME', full_rollback, query_only, no_share_library_data, p_id);
```